# HTML prerequisites for mobile website developpement?

Tags: android, xhtml, mobile-phones, iphone

What is the most advised doctype for a **website** optimised for smartphones?
and what are the principal diferences between them.

XHTML Mobile Profile 1.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

or XHTML Mobile Profile 1.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile11.dtd">
```

or XHTML Mobile Profile 1.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN"
  "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I think of smartphones I think of the ones you have listed in your tags, iPhone and android.

Since these are the two you listed I would suggest `<!DOCTYPE>` which is HTML5.

Webkit is optimized for HTML5 and is the HTML renderer for Android and iOs devices.